# Show/Hide ImageView in Android Toolbar From Main Xamarin Project

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Here's my situation. I've got a Xamarin app for iOS and Android and one of the requirements is that the first "Main" page needs to have the company logo present and centered on the toolbar. All other pages are to show the page title instead of the logo. I had to customize the `toolbar.axml` file in the Android project to get it to display properly using an `ImageView` but it's present on every page now. What I want to know is, is it possible to programmatically access the `ImageView` and set its visibility property to visible from the shared Xamarin project, like the `App.xaml.cs` file or the `MainPage.xaml.cs` file? Or, failing that, is it possible to do this from within the android project, like in the `MainActivity.cs` file?

Here's what my toolbar looks like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/homeLogo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_file"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:paddingRight="50dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I just need to be able to set `homeLogo`'s visibility to visible for the home page. This is my first time really digging in to a true Xamarin project so I'm kind of figuring this all out as I go along here.

Comment: does it work now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use **NavigationPage.TitleView** then custom your style ,

for example,you want let `homeLogo` page has a toolbar with ImageView,you could do this in the `homeLogo.xaml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App11"
         x:Class="App11.MainPage">

  //custom your style
  <NavigationPage.TitleView>
    <StackLayout > 
        <Image Source="ic_action_info.png" /> 
    </StackLayout>
  </NavigationPage.TitleView>


</ContentPage>
```

**PS:** needs Xamarin.Forms 3.2.0 and later

Comment: That did it! Sure, minus any formatting it's enormous and gets cut off, but the functionality is there. Thanks!